# How to use shrink wrap to create vertex group?

Tags: image, hair, vertex-groups, shrinkwrap

I have shrink-wrapped an image onto a sculpted shape as seen here:
[image]

I want to select the black parts of the shrink-wrap on the shape as a vertex group so I can apply hair everywhere on the shape except for the black parts. Is this possible with shrinkwrap, or is there a better way to do this?

I'd rather not have to trace the shapes out manually.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a place for the [*Vertex Weight Proximity*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/weight_proximity.html) modifier, aimed at the Shrinkwrapped features. Possibly followed up with a [*Vertex Weight Edit*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/weight_edit.html) modifier, to fill holes, define edges.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but only if polonium's SW target is that vert dense (and even then, did they ever get live particle density from VG working?)  Otherwise, I'd suspect that a texture bake might end up working better, but of course, that's not remotely live either.

Comment: That seems viable, thanks! I'll give it a try.